# finding submesh in Unity 2017

Tags: unity-game-engine, raycasting

How can I find submesh under my mouse NOT using Raycasting? Is any way to do it? I know how to do it clicking on object and using raycast but completely haven't idea how to id it without it. I need it because of bug in Unity - I can't update version of Unity, so I need to find any solution.

Comment: If you are in 2D you could possibly do it by comparing coordinates, basically doing your own simple collision detection, but if your objects are more complex than rectangles, this will quickly become a non-trivial problem. In 3D it would be similar, if you can 'fix' one of the coordinates or you know the distance. What bug do you encounter in Unity?

Comment: @Piflik it is popular bug unfortunatelly: https://forum.unity.com/threads/raycasts-do-not-register-on-some-meshcolliders-in-webgl-2017-2-4-regression.532449/ Could you write more detailed your idea, because I dont' understand it. It is 3D project.

Answer (score 0):

You can see if your mesh contains the mouse.

You get the position and the size of the mesh which allows you to create a square or a cube (whichever you need) and then you just see if your mouse fits within that square or a cube. If so, then you want to select that mesh.

https://tutorialedge.net/gamedev/aabb-collision-detection-tutorial/

or

If your object was a circle/sphere then you can perform a simple distance check between mesh's origin and mouse, if the distance is <= than the radius of the object, then you want to select that mesh.

http://cgp.wikidot.com/circle-to-circle-collision-detection

It is similar, just instead of using 2nd object, you are using a mouse.

Comment: Sounds good, but I was using triangleIndex from RaycastHit to get submesh. It isn't possible with your method, is it?

Comment: I never used triangleIndex before, but in this method, you would have to loop through all of the submeshes and check whether the mouse is contained in any of them. Once implemented then you can optimise it further. This is the only simple alternative that I could come up with that doesn't use raycasts.

Comment: Another idea is to create a mini collider and attach it to the mouse, and then use collision events. But I doubt it would be very efficient nor clean.